# Example for Ruby JSON.parse option create_additions?

Tags: json, ruby

I'm working on some document enhancements and example code snippets for Ruby's [JSON](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) class. I'm puzzled by this option to [`JSON.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse):

> create_additions: If set to false, the Parser doesn't create additions even if a matching class and `::create_id` was found. This option defaults to false.

Could someone please provide example code for using this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Actually, the SO way is for you to search and research, then when you've exhausted that, ask a specific question detailing where you searched and why those didn't help, in other words tell us what effort you put into solving the question. You're asking us to write a tutorial, but we can't tell if you did your due diligence. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. If you're working with on enhancing the documentation then the JSON maintainers would be a good source.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/index.html might help too as it implements YAML and JSON is a subset of that.

Comment: I only did part of the SO way:  searched and researched, in code, doc, and web, but did not say so.  I found almost nothing.I thought I was asking for a code snippet, not a tutorial.  The place I did not look, but which now gives me hope, is in test/ and spec/ for the module.

Comment: A quick search for "ruby + json + create_additions" would have been useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
require 'json'

class Range
def to_json(*a)
  {
    'json_class'   => self.class.name,
    'data'         => [ first, last, exclude_end? ]
  }.to_json(*a)
end

def self.json_create(o)
  new(*o['data'])
end
end

foo = 1 .. 2
```

Generating JSON:

```
JSON.generate(foo)                              # => "{\"json_class\":\"Range\",\"data\":[1,2,false]}"
JSON.generate(foo, { create_additions: false }) # => "{\"json_class\":\"Range\",\"data\":[1,2,false]}"
JSON.generate(foo, { create_additions: true })  # => "{\"json_class\":\"Range\",\"data\":[1,2,false]}"
```

Parsing the generated JSON:

```
JSON.parse( JSON.generate(foo)                              ) # => {"json_class"=>"Range", "data"=>[1, 2, false]}
JSON.parse( JSON.generate(foo), { create_additions: false } ) # => {"json_class"=>"Range", "data"=>[1, 2, false]}
JSON.parse( JSON.generate(foo), { create_additions: true  } ) # => 1..2
```

"[2.4.3. JSON.parse and JSON.load](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Security_Team/1/html/Secure_Ruby_Development_Guide/ch02s04s03.html)" demonstrates a potential bug in JSON that affected `create_additions`. From there it was a simple thing, just some lines testing the result of toggling the state.

Why they had to close the security hole is for you to research as it involves the specification for JSON serialized data and it being a data-exchange standard, and an example in the JSON docs needs to cover that.

Comment: Thanks @the Tin Man.  Just what I need.

Comment: Tin Man, to give you some idea of what I'm up to, you can see that I've basically rewritten the documentation for Ruby ENV:
- [2.6.5](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/ENV.html)
- [2.7.0](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ENV.html)

Comment: Another example of mine using a regular object:
https://gist.github.com/esquinas/85df587f7faa05095a2ff4414cfb59b8

Answer (score 0):

The example is right there in the documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Extended+rendering+and+loading+of+Ruby+objects.

The main difference in this respect between `parse` and `load` is that the former defaults to not create additions, the latter defaults to do it.

> ### Extended rendering and loading of Ruby objects
>
> provides optional additions allowing to serialize and deserialize Ruby
>   classes without loosing their type.
>
> ```
> # without additions
> require "json"
> json = JSON.generate({range: 1..3, regex: /test/})
> # => '{"range":"1..3","regex":"(?-mix:test)"}'
> JSON.parse(json)
> # => {"range"=>"1..3", "regex"=>"(?-mix:test)"}
>
> # with additions
> require "json/add/range"
> require "json/add/regexp"
> json = JSON.generate({range: 1..3, regex: /test/})
> # => '{"range":{"json_class":"Range","a":[1,3,false]},"regex":{"json_class":"Regexp","o":0,"s":"test"}}'
> JSON.parse(json)
> # => {"range"=>{"json_class"=>"Range", "a"=>[1, 3, false]}, "regex"=>{"json_class"=>"Regexp", "o"=>0, "s"=>"test"}}
> JSON.load(json)
> # => {"range"=>1..3, "regex"=>/test/}
> ```
>
> See #load for details.